# What is a subgenomic promotor?

Tags: molecular-biology, virology, mrna

I am looking for a good definition of the term "subgenomic promotor". Can someone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please read the [tour] and the [Help on asking questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that you are expected to research a problem first before posting here. Where are you looking, or, more precisely, where have you looked for this term? I find an immediate hit to a Wikipedia entry on Googling. If that did not solve your problem you need to explain why and describe (preferably link to) the context in which you met the term so we can check out the context.

Comment: The spelling _promoter_ is most common in this context, which is important if your search mechanism does not return both spellings.

Comment: Can it be a [DNA motif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promoter_(genetics)) where the RNA polymerase will bind to create a subgenomic (m)RNA ?

Answer (score 1):

*A subgenomic promoter is a promoter added to a virus for a specific heterologous gene, resulting in the formation of mRNA for that gene alone. Many positive-sense RNA viruses produce these subgenomic mRNAs (sgRNA) as one of the common infection techniques used by these viruses and generally transcribe late viral genes.* From doi:10.1128/jvi.74.13.5988-5996.2000

So it seems to be an added promoter that helps express certain genes. Often useful in viral engineering.